# How to make a .exe that gives the compiler commands

Tags: c++

I wonder if there is a way to make a .exe that gives the compiler (I use Visual Studio) commands.

For example:

I have `main.cpp`
.
And I want to compile `main.cpp` without opening the IDE or the console.
So I start a program `X.exe`which gives a command to the compiler to compile `main.cpp`.

I heard of Makefiles and Batchfles. But I dont't know how to give other programs commands (if this is even possible).
Basically I want to automate compiling.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you asking if there is a command line compiler with VS? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2019

Comment: Depends on your build system, but yes lots of ways to do this `cmake --build ...` and `msbuild foo.sln ....` and `make -f foo ...`

Comment: The Visual Studio C++ compiler have a command-line program, called `cl.exe`. You can call it any way you would call any other program (e.g. `system`, `ShellExecute`, `CreateProcess`).

Comment: if you're using visual studio code then your exe file is automatically created inside your project folder/ Debug with the project_name.exe

Comment: Yes, you want to invoke the compiler program (cl.exe) from your code. Look into how to spawn a process from C++. Note that it's simpler to do this from other languages. If you look at the Build pane in the VS Output Window, you'll see the command-line arguments that are passed to cl.exe.